# Как узнать имя UI кнопки вызвавшей метод в Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-ui

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Имеется кусок кода:

```
public void Load_Scene(string Scene)
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(Scene);
}
```

Как можно узнать название кнопки (без создания и назначения переменной") что бы взять её название и использовать в

```
SceneManager.LoadScene(кнопка.name);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I вариант:

```
public void Load_Scene(GameObject Scene)
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(Scene.name);
}
```

II вариант:

```
public void Load_Scene()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(gameObject.name);
}
```

III вариант:

```
public void Load_Scene()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(GetComponentInChildren<UnityEngine.UI.Text>(true).text);
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо, но во втором случае мы получаем название объекта  на котором висит скрипт, а не кнопки.

Comment: Вы цитировали код? Цель была избавится от переменных(1 вариант)

Comment: Ну так, надо вопросы корректно задавать, имя кнопки и есть объект на котором висит скрипт, а строка внутри кнопки это вообще Text, лови 3ий вариант

Comment: Вроде же вроде конкретно написал - мне нужно было узнать имя/название кнопки, а не текста, находившегося в ней. Притом, на кнопке скрипт не висит (он на пустышке, в которой этот скрипт) (иначе зачем бы мне находить название кнопки?). Все же спасибо за ваши варианты ответов.

Comment: Без делегирования, ты не сообщишь объекту другой объект, без переменной не обойтись. Теоретически это можно решить, только кода придется писать еще больше, чем просто накинуть объект(само себя как в I варианте)

Comment: Реализую меню с выбором большого кол-во сцен. Хотел написать скрипт , навесить на менеджер(пустышку). Потом в onClick указать пустышку с функцией. В первоначальном варианте, нужно было вводить название сцены (в onClick). Я тут прикинул, что можно же взять название кнопки (какое в инспекторе) и загружать сцену (название кнопки)

Comment: Избегай сериализуемых ссылок на внешние объекты на сцене, т.е. в onclick прокидывать менеджер внешний, захочешь префаб или динамическое создание кнопок, и все полетит к чертям) Лучше на кнопки повесить скрипт, в onclick прокинуть ссылку на этот скрипт и вызывать функцию какую-нибудь, а уже эта функция может как угодно передачу вызова менеджеру( с именем своей кнопки) через глобальное событие, или синглтон или ioc или менеджер сам подписывается на локальное событие в скрипте ит.д. 
Скрипт потом можно дополнять, возможностями блокирования или смены спрайта на кнопке ит.д.. Дерзай)

Comment: Спасибо за советы. (пошел переделывать :D)